# PDF to Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

Just when I think I am finally getting it, such a newb.

I am trying to get a list of numbers from a column from a table that is an PDF.

First step I wanted to convert to a Panda DF.

```
pip install tabula-py
pip install PyPDF2

import pandas as pd
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf('/content/Manifest.pdf')
```

The output I get however is a list of 1, not a DF. When I look at DF the info is there, I just have no idea how access it as it is a list of 1.

So not sure why I didnt get a DF and no idea what I meant to do with a list of 1.[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDutl.png)

Not sure if it matters but I am using google Colab.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, since you're new check out [ask]. You shouldn't be including pictures/images of code. Additionally its difficult to determine what what df should be taking if we don't have sample input (ie the pdf). Also, what is it exactly that you want in your output? Check out the docs for tabula https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html, specifically look at the return type of the function `read_pdf()`

Comment: Thanks for the info, lot to learn, and looks like how to ask questions correctly is one of them. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

tabula.read_pdf returns the list of dataframes without any additional arguments. To access your specific dataframe, you can select the index and use it.

Here's an example where I have read the document and selected the very first index and compared the types

```
import tabula

df = tabula.read_pdf(
    "https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/raw/master/tests/resources/data.pdf")

df_0 = df[0]

print("type of df :", type(df))
print("type of df_0", type(df_0))
```

Returns:

```
type of df : <class 'list'>
type of df_0 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: I have a side question regarding Tabula. It throws an error when I run the tabula.pdf_read() command. An error about "JVM cache being full and to increase its size". Any ideas how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try something as
df = tabula.read_pdf('/content/Manifest.pdf', sep=' ')