# Error: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, attributeerror

When importing the read_pdf method from pandas using

```
import pandas as pd
```

as the example demonstrated

It shows the following **error message**

AttributeError: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

**Environment**

```
python --version: python 3.8.8
OS and it's version: ? windows 10
Anaconda (version 1.7.2)
```

> I was trying to read files that are of type .pdf / .docx / .txt from a file system that is already there.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os # Os moduel for Operating System opertions
import mimetypes

# To change the current working directory to a new directory we use
# os.chdir("Directory path")
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\adity\\Documents\\Parent") 

# To List the files and folders in the current working directory
# Return the file in form of List
fid = os.listdir() #filesInDirectory

# To check whether child 1 2 3 exist or not
def checkChild(d):
    if len(d) == 0:
        return False
    if 'Child1' in d and 'Child2' in d and 'Child3' in d:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# dc1 Directory Child One; dof Dictionary File System
# nof name of file , ext Extension

if checkChild(fid) == True: # if folders are there than read respective files
    for folder in fid:
        fileDir = folder
        os.chdir(directory+f"\\{fileDir}") # Changing directory to respective child
        dc = os.listdir()[0] # dc contains the name of file with extension
        nof,ext = os.path.splitext(dc)        
        if ext =='':
            ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(os.getcwd())
        
        if ext == '.pdf' and fileDir == 'Child1':
            child1Pdf = pd.read_pdf(f'{dc}')  #**Error Line**
```

Error Output:

> *AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
> 9         print(dc)
> 10         if ext == '.pdf' and fileDir == 'Child1':
> ---> 11             child1Pdf = pd.read_pdf(f'{dc}')
> 12
> 13
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init*_.py in **getattr**(name)
> 242         return _SparseArray
> 243
> --> 244     raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
> 245
> 246
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_pdf'*

**I am not getting any solution for this error**

Comment: `pandas` have `read_pdf` function?. I don't think so.

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053943/4985099

Comment: Pandas does not support reading from pdf natively. Here is the list of all available [IO operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-tools-text-csv-hdf5)

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing pdf data as tabular data

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd

#declare the path of your file
file_path = "/path/to/pdf_file/data.pdf

#Convert your file
df = tabula.read_pdf(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just about reading a PDF as pandas dataframe then have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480829/pdf-to-pandas-data-frame/64184817), the answer clearly shows how you can read pdf as pandas dataframe using tabula

```
import tabula

df = tabula.read_pdf(
    "https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/raw/master/tests/resources/data.pdf")

df_0 = df[0]

print("type of df :", type(df))
print("type of df_0", type(df_0))
```

Output

```
type of df : <class 'list'>
type of df_0 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

My bad I just explored the actual package tabula in python and realized there is no read_pdf there, so after digging into this and reproducing the issue my final experiment yields foolowing results

1. Use tabula-io to use the function read_pdf
2. to install run command pip install tabula-py

Use the following code sample

```
from tabula.io import read_pdf
df = read_pdf("https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/raw/master/tests/resources/data.pdf")
df_0 = df[0]
print("type of df :", type(df))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: getting an AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Comment: You are right i just reproduced the issue, updating my answer